# Getting a TableLayout from a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, classcastexception, android-tablelayout

I have created a Fragment whose UI is initialized to look like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TableLayout android:id="@+id/table_other"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             >
....<-- The rows are dynamically added although it is initialized with the first row already inserted-->
</TableLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I am trying to obtain the TableLayout to get the rows which can be added dynamically using:

```
tl=(TableLayout) ((RelativeLayout)f.getView()).getChildAt(0);
```

This throws the error:

```
 AndroidRuntime(1959): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 AndroidRuntime(1959): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v4.app.NoSaveStateFrameLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.RelativeLayout
AndroidRuntime(1959):   at com.example.newcontactlayout.MainActivity.getTableLayoutFromFragment(MainActivity.java:283)
AndroidRuntime(1959):   at com.example.newcontactlayout.MainActivity.saveContact(MainActivity.java:373)
AndroidRuntime(1959):   at com.example.newcontactlayout.MainActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(MainActivity.java:83)
AndroidRuntime(1959):   at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2566)
AndroidRuntime(1959):   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java:372)
```

What should I do to get the TableLayout from the Fragment(the Fragment has been added using XML)??

Comment: `tl=(TableLayout) ((ViewGroup)f.getView()).findViewById(R.id.table_other);`

Comment: @Luksprog Hypothetical question,what if there was no id??

Comment: You use an id of an existent view in the layout(and then move through the view hierarchy starting from that view) or you set an id on the target view even if you don't need the id. Relying on `getView()` to have the exact structure like in your layout is dangerous and has the possibility to fail in the future(like you already seen in your question).